# Ubuntu Cron Job process not release memory automatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, ruby-on-rails-5, rake

We have 1 server, where we run only batches.
Its working very smoothly without any problems but suddenly it's increasing memory.

You can see in EC2 memory utilization graph.
[image]

Before it's take up-to 20% of system memory but now it's taking 80-90% of memory.

After run this command  `killall -o 1h ruby` .
**memory utilization** graph down to around **10%**. So the problem is : *Memory is not released after completed batch process*.

Here, attaching Batch Screenshot also. So it might help you give answer.
[image]

Anyone know, how to resolve this problem ?

**This same rake task code/logic works properly on a test environment with low EC2 spec than production.**

Notes:

- We did not release anything on that server. this spike is suddenly.

Answer (score 0):

There's a small section in Rails guides describing [how to debug memory leaks](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/debugging_rails_applications.html#debugging-memory-leaks).

Also, I recommend you to install [earlyoom](https://github.com/rfjakob/earlyoom). It won't solve your problem, but at least it will prevent your server from getting stuck, killing the process that uses the most memory when available memory falls close to zero.

Comment: I also have the same issue. But in my case, it doesn't seem memory leaking issue because the same logic or code running correctly on a test environment with low EC2 specs. There should be other OS-related issues maybe? It would be very helpful if can suggest any way to debug the CRON session start and stop.